# Closest pair of points nlogn algorithm memory problem

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic

I'm trying to create a program that will calculate the smallest distance between a pair of points and I have no idea how to make my code work. It sometimes appears to work for certain n inputs, but not consistently. I've been getting heap corruption errors, bad array new length and most recently Critical error c0000374 while trying to fix this. I'm guessing it's something very stupid but i'm unable to come up with a solution.

Code is based on:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <random>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <algorithm>
    #define MAX 1;
    struct Point {
        float x;
        float y;
        Point()
        {
            this->x = 0;
            this->y = 0;
        }
        Point(float x, float y) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
        Point *operator=(const Point *other)
        {
            this->x = other->x;
            this->y = other->y;
            return this;
        }
    };
    void merge(Point* &arr, int l, int m, int r) {
        int i, j, k;
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;
        Point *L = new Point[n1];
        Point *R = new Point[n2];
    
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            L[i] = &arr[l + i];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            R[j] = &arr[m + 1 + j];
        }
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2)
        {
            if (L[i].x <= R[j].x)
            {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i < n1)
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    
        while (j < n2)
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    
    void mergeSort(Point* &arr, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l < r)
        {
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            mergeSort(arr, l, m);
            mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
            merge(arr, l, m, r);
        }
    }
    int  compareX(Point a, Point b) {
        return ((float)a.x >= (float)b.x) ? 1 : -1;
    };
    float dist(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) +
            (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y)
        );
    }
    float stripClosest(Point* &strip, int size, float d)
    {
        float min = d; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size && (strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min; ++j)
                if (dist(strip[i], strip[j]) < min)
                    min = dist(strip[i], strip[j]);
        return min;
    }
    float min(float x, float y)
    {
        return (x < y) ? x : y;
    }
    
    float bruteForce(Point P[], int n)
    {
        float min = MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
                if (dist(P[i], P[j]) < min)
                    min = dist(P[i], P[j]);
        return min;
    }
    float closestUtil(Point P[], Point Pi[], int n)
    {
        if (n <= 3)
        {
            return bruteForce(P, n);
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = n / 2;
            Point midPoint = P[mid];
            int li = 0, ri = 0;
            Point* Pyl = new Point[mid+1];
            Point* Pyr = new Point[n - (mid -1)];
            Point* strip = new Point[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (P[i].y <= midPoint.y)
                    Pyl[li++] = Pi[i];
                else
                    Pyr[ri++] = Pi[i];
            }
    
            float dl = closestUtil(P, Pyl, mid);
            float dr = closestUtil(P + mid, Pyr, n - mid);
            float d = min(dl, dr);      
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (abs(P[i].y - midPoint.y) < d)
                    strip[j] = Pi[i], j++;
            return min(d, stripClosest(strip, j, d));
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
    
        int n;
        std::cout << "Input the amount of points" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> n;
        Point* arr = new Point[n];
        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            float xi = distribution(generator);
            float yi = distribution(generator);
            arr[i].x = xi;
            arr[i].y = yi;
        }
        mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            std::cout << arr[i].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << bruteForce(arr, n) << std::endl;
        std::cout << closestUtil(arr, arr, n);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: why do you use so many pointers?

Comment: To begin with, change `Point *operator=(const Point *other)` to `Point &operator=(const Point &other)` and return `*this` at the end of it.

Comment: Formerlyknownas_463035818 Don't really have a good answer to that, I've been trying pretty much everything that came to my mind in the past few hours and this is the most recent state of my code.

@goodvibration changed it, still doesn't work except for certain cases like n=5 or n=15

Comment: this is lots of code with lots of problems, many of them related to not using `std::vector`

Comment: when programming you need to learn to split problems into smaller chunks. This whole code is just too much to get right in one go. Concentrate on seperate parts, write tests, only move on when you know the code you already have works fine.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sorry for not specifying earlier, the problem most likely lies in closestUtil function, every other part works fine on it's own but i provided the entire code just in case the problem in closestUtil is caused by some other part of the code.

Comment: ok, my comment still holds. Analogy: If you want to fix a seat in your car you dont do that while riding at full speed through the desert. You take the seat out of the car fix it and put it back in. Create a test case that contains only code you want to test, not more, make it pass the test, only then add complexity

Answer (score 3):

In C++ we have [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that obviates the need for all those `new`s. We also have very useful [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) macro. The website you mentioned ignores all the good practices and contains a lot of examples of very bad code and better be avoided.

I won't fix your code, but will give you a hint that might be helpful. If you recompile the code with

```
clang++ -fsanitize=address -g 1.cpp
```

and run it, you'll see something like this:

```
WRITE of size 8 at 0x606000000120 thread T0
    #0 0x4937cf in __asan_memcpy (/tmp/0/a.out+0x4937cf)
    #1 0x4c886b in closestUtil(Point*, Point*, int) /tmp/0/1.cpp:133:31
    #2 0x4c9246 in main /tmp/0/1.cpp:172:22
    #3 0x7fbbc46ddb6a in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-KRRWSm/glibc-2.29/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
    #4 0x41c3d9 in _start (/tmp/0/a.out+0x41c3d9)
```

Position `1.cpp:133` corresponds to this line in your code:

```
Point* Pyl = new Point[mid+1];
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (P[i].y <= midPoint.y)
        Pyl[li++] = Pi[i];          // << ERROR IS HERE
    else
        Pyr[ri++] = Pi[i];
}
```

What's going on? If you insert aforementioned `assert(li < mid + 1);` before `if`, recompile and rerun the program, you'll see that assertion fails. That is you're accessing `Pyl` array outside its bounds, and this is undefined behavior. Careful analysis of your code will tell you the reason. After fixing this error, you can repeat the above procedure to find other errors (if any).

Comment: After converting that code to proper C++, I confirmed the error.  Visual C++ reports a vector out-of-bounds error.

Comment: @Evg Thanks for trying to help, sadly i still can't get it to work after juggling the values. I've tried switching the midpoint depending on whether n is even or odd, changing Pyl and Pyr sizes, <= to <  and changing dr declaration - all i've achieved is switching the n values the program crashes at.

Comment: `std::vector` isnt that "modern" ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, indeed.